# PHP7 - Behave differently in ob_start

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I was using this function in my MVC cms to put data array in my php file with buffer (ob_start and ob_get_clean) and it was working in php5!

```
private static function template ($path, $data = array(), $layout) 
{
    extract($data);
    ob_start();
    include __ROOT__ . "/assets/views/$layout/$path.php";
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    require_once(__ROOT__ . "/assets/templates/$layout/index.php");
}
```

Now I'm switching to php7 but it didn't work anymore! and it shows codes directly in my browser!

What is exactly changed in php7?

Comment: I solved the problem, that was because I didn't enabled shot open tags!

Answer (score 1):

i guess that's because your php7 libraries are not installed or some modules are not enabled
so..
if you are on ubuntu/debian.
just open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

will install everything you need and will start the apache server with support for PHP7.

if not enabled, then load with:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and if you are on windows, just visit **[this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_installation_windows_apache.htm)** website

pirooz bashi ;)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I used this commands on terminal but it first go to download oracle-java8-installer (whitch I can not download because of oracle sanction). Also I am using shadowsocks proxy but when I use http_proxy command in terminal and use proxy for downloading it I got ERROR 503 :( Do u have any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: And also I don't know exactly but I can run php codes! but this code can not fill buffer code with datas. Does it need to install these packages?